# Add environment variable to product flavor

Tags: android, android-flavors

I want to define an environment variable that is specific to a particular product flavor but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried adding the following

```
buildConfigField "string", "APP_TYPE", "\"demo\""
```

But I receive the error

```
BuildConfig.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
  public static final string APP_TYPE = "demo";
```

My project is a React Native project and I am looking to set an environment variable which I can use in the Metro Bundler.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, `String` has a capital `S`. Yours does not, and so the generated code will not compile.

So, switch to:

```
buildConfigField "String", "APP_TYPE", "\"demo\""
```

Note that this is not really an environment variable. If you mean that you will be replacing `"\"demo\""` with the contents of an environment variable, just bear in mind that Android Studio does not expose environment variables to its builds, while command-line builds (e.g., Gradle) will.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the desire is not to switch out the "demo" but pass demo into the JS bundler. The same can be achieved by executing `APP_TYPE=demo react-native run-android`. I wonder how the value of `demo` can be different depending on my flavor

Comment: @Dan: Have one `buildConfigField` entry per flavor, in your `productFlavors` closure.

Comment: Adding `buildConfigField "String", "APP_TYPE", "\"demo\""` to each flavor didn't seem to work here. Logging out `process.env` in the bundler does not seem to contain `APP_TYPE`.

Comment: @Dan: `buildConfigField` only creates a field in the generated `BuildConfig` type, in terms of standard Android development. I would be surprised if it affected anything else, even in React Native. You might want to ask a separate question, without the `buildConfigField` part and with a React Native tag, to ask how to affect `process.env` on a per-flavor basis.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of time searching how to achieve this.

To provide some environment variables to React Native you need to provide them to Metro server.

Metro server actually starts *before* build.gradle executed. Not sure if you can configure this to switch places in latest version of React Native.

I ended up creating custom .sh script that write simple .txt file with a string (in my case I needed only one variable, but you can work on placing different variables here):

```
PAREMETER_VALUE="$1"
TARGET_FILE="temp.txt"

echo "Writing value: $PAREMETER_VALUE to $TARGET_FILE..."
echo "$PAREMETER_VALUE" > "$TARGET_FILE"
echo "Value written."
```

I added this script into package.json before running "react-native run-android" command:

```
"env-staging": "./scripts/write-env-file.sh staging",
"run:android:staging": "npm run env-staging && yarn android --variant stagingDebug",
```

And the last one - Metro should read this file and upload value to actual process.env (metro.config.js):

```
let envValue = process.env.ENV_VARIABLE || 'defaultValue';

// Get the current app environment from the temp.txt file
try {
  envValue = fs.readFileSync('./temp.txt', 'utf8').trim();
} catch (error) {
  console.warn(
    'Failed to read temp.txt file.',
  );
}

process.env.ENV_VARIABLE = envValue;
```